# Cannot unset session in java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have a logout.jsp page, which is used to invalidate the session,Here is its contents :

```
session.invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
```

In my profile.jsp page I want to check whether the session variable is set or not and depending on that allow the user to browse the page or redirect back to the login page(if the session variable is not set)

```
if(request.getSession(false)==null){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```

But the problem is that this is not working as on opening the profile.jsp page from address bar directly, even when there is no user logged in ,it opens without redirecting to the login page.Further on printing `request.getSession(false)` I get the output `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@ad4a7e`. I don't know what this is and haven't found anything about it in the Internet. So how to solve this issue.

**EDIT :**

The class 'user' whose object I am using as the session variable implements serializable,so can that be the reason of the issue I am facing.

I am not being permitted to comment so I mentioned it here.
I use chrome which accepts cookies....further I tried the same in Microsoft Edge but it is still the same

Comment: A JSP makes a session automatically unless you tell it not to make one. Usually we put an attribute in session and check whether that attribute is set.

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well: `if(session.getAttribute("user")==null){
 response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");}
System.out.println(session.getAttribute("user"));` here user is the session variable attribute and console output is `mypack.user@1ad20a7` where mypack is the name of package I have a 'user' named class. whose object I am using as session variable

Comment: It is not redirecting

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. It works for me. You should also add  <%=" sessionId is " + session.getId()%> to both pages to see if session is the same.

Comment: session.getId() gives different values in my login.jsp page where I have not even logged in.

Comment: If the id values are different,  then a session is not being maintained. Is your browser configured to accept cookies? Please try a different browser.

Comment: A better approach would be to have single point of control for your application.Use a filter to screen client requests for valid session.This way you will not have to validate session on each and every page also will have a central location to validate or control application flow

Comment: Also,try using this <%@page session='false'%> to avoid creating session by jsp,when a one is not available readily

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have created the servlets for login and logout and then from corresponding servlets you can redirect to the page:
This may be your login servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("userName", email);
    session.setAttribute("password", password);
   getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/profile.jsp").forward(request, 
    response);
    }
```

This can be your profile.jsp page code to check the session:

```
 <%
if(!(request.getSession(true).getAttribute("userName").toString()).isEmpty()){
  String firstName = (String)request.getAttribute("firstName");
 String lastName = (String)request.getAttribute("lastName");
 }else{%>
 <jsp:forward page = "Login.jsp" />
<% }%>
```

From logout Page you can just send request to the logoutservlet. And, this can be your logoutservlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.invalidate();
    out.println("Logout Successful");
    out.println("Username : "+session.getAttribute("userName"));
    out.println("Password : "+session.getAttribute("password"));

}
```

After then when I am getting the credentials from session I am getting null values for those fields.

Comment: `<%=request.getSession(true).getAttribute("userName").toString().isEmpty()%> ` returns false...I tried the above method and in my logout page `request.getSession(false)` returns null but on opening the profile.jsp page (without logging in) it returns true...if you want to see any specific file of mine you can mention I will add it here.